# SSRS 2008 Report History not using changed RDL template

Tags: reporting-services, report, history, snapshot, rdl

We have migrated our application and reports from SQL 2005 to SQL 2008 R2. After testing, we found that Excel format of the report in both SSRS 2005 & SSRS 2008 R2 is different.

We have fixed this in the RDL file and uploaded that file in SSRS 2008. So, from that day/time onwards the format is correct. But when we download the history reports from SSRS 2008, they are still showing report in older format.

Is there any way we can point history reports to refer latest RDL file so that older reports would appear in proper format.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are referring to the report snapshots history. When report snapshots are created they include the report definition as it was at the time the snapshot was generated, and so will always use this definition. This cannot be changed, so there is no way to alter the format of historical snapshots from before you changed the report definition.

More information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms156325.aspx